# How do I tell which users are connected to a shared tmux socket?

Tags: sockets, tmux

I have created a shared socket for tmux to use.

```
tmux -S /tmp/pair
```

Then I have a 2nd user attach to the socket.

```
tmux -S /tmp/pair attach
```

How do I tell from the first session, the one that created the socket, tell that the 2nd user is connected?

I'm guessing it would be something from the `lsof` command.

Comment: From inside tmux? `Ctrl-b D`

Comment: @hroptatyr You mean `<prefix> D`, yes? :/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `list-clients` command. By itself, it displays all clients connected to the server. If you specify a session with the `-t` option, it shows clients attached to the named session.

Answer (score 14):

Like another user said in comments `<prefix> D` will list all the sessions but keep in mind that pressing enter will detach that client (which may or may not be what you want)

Comment: Attention: That's Shift-D, without shift, you get detached from the session yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given (Ctrl-b D  or Ctrl-b : list-clients RET) will give you a list of clients with their (virtual) tty terminal and window size, but does NOT tell you the associated username.  From outside of a tmux session, you can also use "tmux -S /tmp/pair list-clients"

One method to list actual users that are connected is to run lsof on the named socket, ie: "lsof /tmp/pair"

Or you can use the 'who' command to view a listing of users associated with the virtual terminals.  If you are just differentiating between your own connections, you can use an alis to filter that: "who | awk '{print $2,$NF}' |grep -v '(:[0-9]'"

Here's a quick Perl script that puts the tmux and 'who' outputs together.  For usage with shared sockets, pass the socket file as the sole argument, ie: "tmux_ls.pl /tmp/shared":

```
my $sock="";
$sock = "-S ".$ARGV[0] if $ARGV[0];

my $clients = `tmux $sock list-clients`;

# Use open to loop like a file
open my $fh, '<', \$clients or die $!;

printf("%-10.10s\t%-10.10s\t%-10.10s\t%-16.16s\t%s\n", "Session", "TTY", "Username", "Timestamp", "Origin");
while(<$fh>) {
    my @cols = split(' ');
    my ($tty) = $cols[0] =~ /^\/dev\/(pts\/\d+)/;
    my $session = $cols[1];
    my $who = `who | grep $tty`;
    my @whoc = split(' ',$who);

    printf("%-10.10s\t%-10.10s\t%-10.10s\t%-16.16s\t%s\n", $session,$tty,$whoc[0], "$whoc[2] $whoc[3]", $whoc[4]);
}
```